# Shortcode of woocommerce variation description

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, product-variations

Is there a way to get a variable variation description of a product?

When I set the description it appears between the variation selection and the add to cart button.

I tried already with something like this, but it didn't work:

```
function vardesc_sc( ){
   return get_variation_description();
}
add_shortcode( 'variation_descr', 'vardesc_sc' );
```

Maybe you can help me.

Comment: Do you want to move the variation description somewhere else?

Comment: Hi, yes. I want to embed it in an elementor tab. https://sottoluce-test.webdesign-fox.de/produkte/deckenleuchte-sotto-luce-akai-s-1-cp/ Over here in the "VAR"  oder "Details" Tab, so if you switch the variation the right description will be shown.

Comment: I have added the answer please check. Took some time but finally achieved the goal.

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution. Can you tell me how to input it with Elementor? I've put the code to functions.php. What else I need to do?

Comment: Okay, can you tell me how did you create the new tab VAR?

Comment: Yes. I did it with the Pagebuilder Elementor - https://elementor.com/

Comment: Okay, then replace the callback function with mine.

Comment: But I don't know what a callback function is.

Comment: Ohh!! Can you try adding this whole code to the functions.php file of your current theme and check and remove the new elementor tab you have created?

Comment: It works perfect with the common tabs of my theme, but not working with elementor. How can I use it with the elementor tabs?

Comment: Sorry but I am not getting what are you trying to say by using "Elementor Tabs". If you add the code I have added it will surely resolve the core question.

Comment: I'm creating the tabs with the Plugin "Elementor". This are not the tabs from the theme. Thats why I needed the shortcode, because all the fields in the tab and the tab itself was custom made. The code is included in functions.php. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this code. Replace your tab callback function accordingly.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'VAR_product_tab' );

function VAR_product_tab( $tabs ) {

    $tabs['custom_tab'] = array(
        'title'    => __( 'VAR', 'woocommerce' ),
        'priority' => 50,
        'callback' => 'VAR_product_tab_content',
    );
    return $tabs;
}

function VAR_product_tab_content() {
    global $product;
    $product_id = $product->get_id();

    ?>
    <div class="new-variation">Please select <div>
    <script>
        jQuery( 'input.variation_id' ).on( 'change', function(){
        var product_id = <?php echo $product_id; ?> 
         if( '' != jQuery(this).val() ) {
             var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>";
             var var_id = jQuery(this).val();
             jQuery.ajax({
             type : "POST",
             dataType : "json",
             url : ajaxurl,
            data : {action: "get_data", variation_id: var_id, product_id: product_id},
             success: function(response) {
                   jQuery('.new-variation').html(response)
            }
        }); 
         }
      });
    </script>
    <?php
}


add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_data', 'my_ajax_handler' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_data', 'my_ajax_handler' );

function my_ajax_handler() {
    $product_id   = $_POST['product_id'];
    $product      = wc_get_product( $product_id );
    $variation_id = $_POST['variation_id'];

    $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
    foreach ( $variations as $variation ) {
        if ( $variation_id == $variation['variation_id'] ) {
            $variation_description = $variation['variation_description'];
            wp_send_json( $variation_description );
            die();
        }
    }
}
```